# Black background on Angular nvd3 LineChart

Tags: css, d3.js, nvd3.js, linechart

I am trying to implement angular D3 Line Chart with angular-nvd3 library. We are using `AngularJS 1.6` with `ES6`. This is how angular-nvd3 is wired:

**app.js**

```
import angularnvd3 from '../node_modules/angular-nvd3/index';
export default angular.module('myApp', othermodules,..angularnvd3)
.
.
```

**controller.js**

```
this.linechartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'lineChart',
      height: 300,
      width:500,
      x: function(d){ return d.x },
      y: function(d){ return d.y },
      useInteractiveGuideline: true,
      xAxis: {
          axisLabel: 'X Label'
      },
      yAxis: {
          axisLabel: 'Y Label',
      },
    },
    title: {
      enable: true,
      text: 'Some text',
      css: {
        'font-size' : '15px',
        'font-weight' : 'bold',
        'text-align' : 'left'
      }
    },
};

this.linechartData = [{
    values: lineChartData,
    key: 'Some Key',
    color: '#1f77b4'
}]
```

**template.html**

```
<nvd3 options="controller.linechartOptions" data="controller.linechartData"></nvd3>
```

However, the graphs get painted with a black background.
[image]

I have been referring to these resources:

- http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart
- http://plnkr.co/edit/lBKFld?p=preview

However I can't figure out how to remove the black background and the lines that create the filled area. I simply need to view the line graph  as shown in the plunker mentioned above.

Comment: The line fill css should be `yourlineSelector{fill:none;}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply include `nv.d3.css` from `node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.css` and it will fix this issue.

Comment: exactly my problem

Comment: If the project is using scss: In angular.json file:
```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "node_modules/nvd3/build/"
  ]
},
```
Finally, in style.scss file:
```
@import "nv.d3";
```